# mv: cannot stat [DIRECTORY/FILE]: no such file or directory

Tags: bash

EDIT: `DIR_trash="trash"`

I wrote a function to move a file to current directory.

```
if [ "$1" == "-u" ]
then
    if [ $# == 1 ]
    then
        echo "Something went wrong. Please make sure you're passing the name of the file/directory after '-u'."
    else
        if [ -f $DIR_trash/$2.zip ]
        then
            echo "$2.zip has been found in the trash."
            cd
            cd $DIR_trash
            sed -i "/$2/d" $file7
            mv -i /$DIR_trash/$2.zip .
            unzip $2.zip
            \rm $2.zip
            cd
        else
            echo "$2.zip has not been found in the trash."
        fi
    fi
fi
```

As you can see, there is a line of code which says:

```
mv -i /DIR_trash/$2.zip .
```

So basically I'm trying to move a file that I passed in argument 2 to current directory, from trash. I always run this script from home directory, which does have trash directory. This is what I get when I run this:

[image: Error file]

Whenever I manually write this is in the Konsole (from home direcotry) it does work:

```
rm -u trash/d1 .
```

I'm out of ideas. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you run the script with the current directory being `/some/where`, and with the arguments `-u` and `d1`. I'll also assume that your home directory is `/home/ninini`. Let's look at where your script looks for files.

> ```
> DIR_trash="trash"
>         if [ -f $DIR_trash/$2.zip ]
> ```

You check if `/some/where/trash/d1.zip` exists.

> ```
>             cd
>             cd $DIR_trash
> ```

Assuming both `cd` commands succeed, the current directory is now `/home/ninini/trash`.

> ```
>             mv -i /$DIR_trash/$2.zip .
> ```

You're saying to move `/trash/d1.zip` to the current directory, which is `/home/ninini/trash`.

Neither the source nor the destination make sense. The source `/$DIR_trash` doesn't make sense: why would you be looking for a directory called `trash` under the root directory? And the destination doesn't make sense since you just attempted to change to the trash directory, and now you're attempting to move a file out of the trash directory… into the trash directory.

I can't tell what the correct code is because you didn't say what the script is meant to do. You do say that you want to “to move a file to current directory”; then you must not change the current directory midway through the script! Assuming that the path `$DIR_trash/$2.zip` from the test command is the correct one, remove the `cd` commands and write

```
             mv -i -- "$DIR_trash/$2.zip" .
```

Note that this moves the file from a directory called `trash` under the current directory. If this isn't what you wanted, you need to change the definition of `DIR_trash`. It should probably be an absolute path, perhaps

```
DIR_trash=~/trash
```

Note also that your script breaks on files containing whitespace and other special characters. Always put double quotes around variable substitutions: `"$VAR"`, not `$VAR`. (Exception: when you know you need some effect that the double quotes prevent, and you understand why it's safe to leave them out.)